# Постоянно активная ссылка на jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Есть код, для обновления части страницы без перезагрузки. Одна ссылка при нажатии постоянно остается активной, вот единственное не могу сделать чтоб при открытии страницы активная ссылка **activ_but** оставалась постоянно открытой. предлагалось использовать trigger, но что-то у меня не получается

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 var user = <?=$uss?>;
    var ser = <?=$id_s?>; 
    $('.watch-s a').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
        $('.watch-s .activ_but').removeClass('activ_but');
        $(this).addClass('activ_but');

  if ($('#knopa1').attr('class') == 'activ_but'){
    $.ajax({
     }
   });
  }
      
  if ($('#knopa2').attr('class') == 'activ_but'){
    $.ajax({
     }
    });
  }
      
  if ($('#knopa3').attr('class') == 'activ_but'){
    $.ajax({
     }
    });
  }
      
  if ($('#knopa4').attr('class') == 'activ_but'){ 
    $.ajax({
     }
    });
  }

   var rzd = $(this).attr("rzd");
   jQuery.ajax({
   });
    });

});
```

Comment: Что значит "ссылка постоянно открытой" ? В общем не понятно что вам нужно и не понятно что в представленном вами коде не работает. Уточните

Comment: при нажатии на ссылку на странице(например page.php) появляется другая динамическая часть страницы, а мне нужно, чтоб при заходе на страницу page.php одна из динамических частей была уже открыта(та которая имеет класс activ_but)

Comment: Советую вам не изобретать велосипед, а использовать плагин jquery.tabs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(function() {
  $("#urls a").each(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
      $("#content").load($(this).attr("href"));
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="urls">
  <a class="active" href="index.html">active</a>
  <br>
  <a class="notactive" href="page.html">not active</a>
</div>
<div id="content"></div>
```

Comment: Все же сделал с triggle, но спасибо ваш скрипт навел на правильную мысль $(function() {
  $(".watch a").each(function() {
    if ($('#btn1').hasClass("activ_but")) {
      $('#btn1').trigger('click');
    }